# How to set the width of a view to a percentage of *some* other ancestor view?

Tags: android, android-layout, view, android-recyclerview

I have a RecyclerView with a width of match_parent.

Inside it, inside of another (horizontal) RecyclerView, there's a few ImageViews. 
I would like to set the width of those imageviews to be a percentage (e.g. 66%) of the width of the top level RecyclerView?

My current way to solve this is to get the screenwidth somewhere in the activity and scale the ImageViews accordinly, but that's a pretty terrible solution...

What's the best way to do this?

Comment: You can use PercentRelativeLayout:
http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/support/percent/PercentRelativeLayout.html

Comment: I need this to work for items of Recyclerviews, so I don't think PercentLayout will do the job.

Comment: You can use PercentRelativeLayout as a parent of each item

Comment: @ARP: That will indeed set the width of the image to my size, but then there's space between the images. I need a solution where childviews are 66% of the inner recyclerview, without any borders.

Comment: Try to put in yout ImageVew xml this: android:scaleType="fitXY"

Comment: I'm sorry, that won't work either.

Answer (score -1):

Use weightsum for your parent view
Use weight for childs

Eg:android:weightsum=1 for RecyclerView

android:weight=0.5 for first imageview(50%)

android:weight=0.5 for second imageview(50%)

Comment: The number of imageviews changes, so that won't work. AFAIK weight only works in a LinearLayout.